# Click doesn't work in Jquery

Tags: jquery

When I click in `membrosClick` this div might have 766px. And the div `listagemDesc` desapear. This is working perfectly. But, there is a div whithin called `membrosFechar`, it's a *X* that I've made when the user click it the Div `listagemDesc` need to be `display:none`. But, it's doesn't work.

You can look it in http://www.musicalabertura.com.br/site/ in **INTEGRANTES**.

My code:

```js
$(".membrosClick").click(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  el.css("width", "766px");
  el.children().show();
});

$('.membrosFechar').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent('.membrosClick').width(383);
});
```

```html
<li class="membrosClick">
  <div name="Listagem de Membros" style="background-image: url('./imagens/EDGAR-GUERRA.png'); width:383px; height:849px">
    <div class="editable subir">
      <h2>Edgar</h2>
      <h3>Guerra</h3> 
      <div class="bandaBarra bandaBarraBranca margin-left-65 margin-top-10 barraNone"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="listagemEsc p-relative">
    <div class="membrosFechar"></div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo.</span>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="membrosClick">
  <div name="Listagem de Membros" style="background-image: url('./imagens/ANTONIO-GUERRA.png'); width:383px; height:849px">
    <div class="editable subir">
      <h2>Antônio</h2>
      <h3>Guerra</h3> 
      <div class="bandaBarra bandaBarraBranca margin-left-65 margin-top-10 barraNone"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="listagemEsc p-relative">
    <div class="membrosFechar"></div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo.</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I think it's because the click on `.membrosFechar` also registers on the parent `.membrosClick`, so it cancels itself. Try stopping the event propagation. http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Indeed.. most likely you need to call `stopPropagation()` on the event.

Comment: @sebnukem Wow, you're right! This worked fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click on `.membrosFechar` bubbles up and also registers on the parent `.membrosClick`, so it cancels itself. Try stopping the event propagation:

```
$('.membrosFechar').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().parent('.membrosClick').width(383);
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/